# How can I opt out of a CSS style on a case-by-case basis?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS style that I need for most input elements, namely:

```
input{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0 0 -2px;
}
```

However, there are a couple of cases where I want the input element to be much less wide than that. How can I accomplish that? It seems to me it should be something like:

```
<input type="date" style="width=100px"></input>
```

...to override the 100% width, but that doesn't work. I binged for "opt out of css style application" and similar phrases, but did not find what I need.

Comment: Your problem isn't the other stylesheet. Inline stylesheets will always override both external and internal stylesheets. [\[1\]](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: need to see the other css being applied first. If it were me i'd use `input[type=date]` to apply the main styles and then use class for the unique cases.

Comment: _" I binged for"_ ... [well there's your problem](http://www.gagbay.com/images/2012/03/well_theres_your_problem-56537.jpg)

Comment: @weirdev, your assertion is incorrect. External and embedded styles marked `!important` will override inline styles (unless the inline style also has `!important`).

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for the info! I've never made use of `!important`. But in general--all else being equal--inline styles do take precedent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use : instead of =

```
<input type="date" style="width:100px"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have another style rule with a more specific selector, which will be applied to that type / those types.

```
input[type=date] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

As demonstrated in this snippet...

```css
input {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
input[type=date] {
    width: 120px;
}
label:after {
    content: ': ';
}
div.inputs {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #f7f7e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
    <label for="first">First</label><input type="text" name="first" id="first" /><br/>
    <label for="second">Second</label><input type="text" name="second" id="second" /><br/>
    <label for="thedate">Date</label><input type="date" name="thedate" id="thedate" /><br/>
    <label for="fourth">Fourth</label><input type="text" name="fourth" id="fourth" /><br/>
</div>
```

Or here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/5ygmj08j/1/) demonstrating it.

Answer (score 1):

Use classes.

For the inputs you want at full width do this:

HTML

```
<input type="date" class="full-width"></input>
```

CSS

```
input.full-width {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5px 0 0 -2px;
    }
```

---

For the inputs you want at, let's say, 80%, do this:

HTML

```
<input type="date" class="short-width"></input>
```

CSS

```
input.short-width {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 5px 0 0 -2px;
}
```

---

I suggested classes because in your question you mentioned "a couple of cases" where you want to make a change. Hence, with a class you only have to make a style change once, and in one place, and all elements with that class will get the message. This is a good way to minimize maintenance and troubleshooting.

If you're only looking to make the style change in ONE element, then going with an inline style has its benefits. There are many other benefits to inline styles, but they're outside the scope of this question.

Lastly, I added the element selectors (`input`) in the CSS blocks above only to increase [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). But chances are you're safe to remove them and just use the class names (i.e., `.full-width` and `.short-width`).